# Reading XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<Tasks>
    <AuxFiles>
        <FileType AttachmentType='csv' FileFormat ='*.csv'>
    </AuxFiles>
</Tasks>
```

What is the syntax in C# to get the `FileFormat` if I know the `AttachmentType`?

Any and all help is always appreciated.

Comment: Is your question: Given this xml file I want to find the Fileformat attribute value for a given AttachtmentType ? So you want to find "*.csv" when you look for "csv" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
string fileFormat = string.Empty;


XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(fileName);

XmlNodeList auxFilesList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("AuxFiles");
for (int i = 0; i < auxFilesList.Count; i++)
{
   XmlNode item = classList.Item(i);
   if (item.Attributes["AttachmentType"].Value == "csv")
   {
      fileFormat = item.Attributes["FileFormat"].Value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd use LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

var format = doc.Descendants("FileType")
                .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("AttachmentType") == type)
                .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("FileFormat"))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will give `null` if there is no matching element or if the first `FileType` with a matching `AttachmentType` doesn't have a `FileFormat` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `XElement` and the query support for that.

```
        XElement element = XElement.Parse(@"<Tasks>
  <AuxFiles>
    <FileType AttachmentType='csv' FileFormat ='*.csv' />
  </AuxFiles>
</Tasks>");
        string format = element.Descendants("FileType")
            .Where(x => x.Attribute("AttachmentType").Value == "csv")
            .Select(x => x.Attribute("FileFormat").Value)
            .First();

        Console.WriteLine(format);
```

Comment: Jon Skeet's solution is more robust than this one, since it won't cause a `NullReferenceException` if there are no types matching or if the element doesn't have a FileFormat attribute. But the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPATH to query any element in your XML file.

see this ULR: http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm

check also this SO post: "How to query a peer XMLNode .NET"

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("path\\to\\file.xml");

// Select the node where AttachmentType='csv'
XmlNode node = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Tasks/AuxFiles/FileType[@AttachmentType='csv']");
// Read the value of the Attribute 'FileFormat'
var fileFormat = node.Attributes["FileFormat"].Value;
```